# Error in cmd prompt for getting MD5 fingerprint

Tags: android, keytool

I want to get MD5 finger print in Android for google map, but when I try to run it in a command window it shows the message below.  How do I overcome this problem?

Command Line:

```
C:\>C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -key
store C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh\.android\debug.keystore -storepass andro
id -keypass android
```

Error:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this simple command
keytool -list -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh.android\debug.keystore"..

Thats it.. Enter twice..

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
C:>cd C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin
```

first and then from bin, execute the ketool.exe
the command for it is:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -key store C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh.android\debug.keystore -storepass andro id -keypass android
```

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -key sto
re C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -
keypass android
Illegal option:  -key
Try keytool -help

Comment: Use jdk1.6.0_07 in place of jre6

Comment: i used jdk1.6.0 but having same problem as above

Comment: the word keystore is a single word..remove unnecessary space

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh\.android\debug.keystore" 
-storepass android -keypass android

Access is denied.

Comment: when i enter in command promt showig showing msg...   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe is not a valid win 32 applicaton when i press ok showing C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android Access is denied.

Comment: @JaydeepKhamar Wah wah what a progress. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the path C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh contains a folder .android. If not, choose the path that contains .android ( if you dont know where, then if you are using eclipse, go to Window->Preferences->Android->Build and check Default debug keystore path and give that instead of C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh.android\debug.keystore

running the following code should get you the MD5 fingerprint if you are giving the right debug keystore path... note that there is a '\' before .android which you had missed in the previous posts

C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin>keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh.android\debug.keystore -storepass andro id -keypass android