# problem in cmd prompt for getting MD5 fingerprint in android

Tags: android, keytool

Having overcome my [earlier problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932759/problem-in-cmd-prompt-for-getting-md5-fingerprint), I am still having difficulty generating an MD5 fingerprint for Android from the command line.  Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Command line:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Error:

```
**Illegal option:  -key
Try keytool -help**
```

Comment: solution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305938/how-can-i-get-the-md5-fingerprint-from-javas-keytool-not-only-sha-1

Answer (score 4):

It's probably that you mistyped the path. I guess your command should look like

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Saurabh\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android
```

The difference is in the slash before .android\debug.keystore and the quotes around the path containing spaces.

Comment: @saounkine when i write this and press enter it shows a prompt message that...C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>keytool.exe is not a valid win32 application and when i pree OK on it ..it shows..access is denied..

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. I couldn't get MD5 key in JDK1.7 (Keytool on JDK 1.7 always return SHA1 key) . I removed JDK 1.7 then installed JDK 1.6, the problem wasn't exist any more.

Comment: hey refer to this link it may solve ur problem http://www.androidpeople.com/android-google-map-application-example    :)

Comment: The problem is that keytool return SHA1 key insted of MD5 key. So, when I pass this key to Google Map API signup page (my purpose is to register to use google map api).

Comment: No Need to Down grade Java Version you can get MD5 Key for JRE-7 [here](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=md5%20key%20in%20android&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDQQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvenomvendor.blogspot.com%2F2012%2F01%2Fcreating-md5-key-for-android.html&ei=_lQuT62EIsXsrAeW59WlAw&usg=AFQjCNFU8f_vN611babcqBU8QdZ3JC_lQA&cad=rja)